# Link 2 variables together

Tags: python-2.7, scripting, pattern-matching, modifiers

I wanted to know how to match a string between the column. For ex:

```
A.      B.     C.    D.     E.    F. 
1.       2.     3.     4.     5.    6
```

In above example let Alphabet be column name and digits are considered as values in the column.

So, i want to match Column A , Value 1 and Column E , Value 5. Values in Column A and E is different.

I'm using something like (A + '.*' + E)
To get something like - 1.    5.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks, :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use dictionaries?

```
>>>dic = {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
>>>print(dic[A])
1
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Elodin! thank you for the help. I will try this.. If some pattern matching expression is there it would be more helpful.. :)